# How to send an NSDictionary (or plist file) as NSData using GameKit bluetooth?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdictionary, nsdata, gamekit

I'm trying to use

```
[currentSession sendDataToAllPeers:data withDataMode:GKSendDataReliable error:nil];
```

to send an NSDictionary (or a plist file) containing data from 1 device to another, and

```
- (void)receiveData:(NSData *)data fromPeer:(NSString *)peer inSession:(GKSession *)session context:(void *)context
```

to receive it. How can I convert to and from NSData for this to happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following to transform Plist to NSData:

```
+ (NSData *)dataWithPropertyList:(id)plist
                          format:(NSPropertyListFormat)format
                         options:(NSPropertyListWriteOptions)opt
                           error:(NSError **)error
```

And this to transform NSData to Plist:

```
+ (id)propertyListWithData:(NSData *)data
                   options:(NSPropertyListReadOptions)opt
                    format:(NSPropertyListFormat *)format
                     error:(NSError **)error
```

of [`NSPropertyListSerialization`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPropertyListSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class

`format` could be `NSPropertyListBinaryFormat_v1_0` to use lowest byte count